# How to navigate through PageView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to make widgets behind a PageView clickable by wrapping it around a GestureDetector, but it doesn't work.

Is there another way I can do this?

My code:

```
 new GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        child: new PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: _buildForegroundPages(),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: do you want widgets inside your pageview clickables?

Comment: yes i have 3 pages in pageview i just want to go in 3 diffrent pages through those pageview

Comment: what's the issue that you have?

Comment: i didn't know the method

Comment: hmm I don't understand the question, did you read the docs? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html    ,  why are you using gesturedetector?   PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: _buildForegroundPages(),
        )  , just should work

Comment: i have 3 pages in page view 1-red 2-green 3-yellow. they are scrolling fine but if i need to press red and and navigate to new materialpageroute how can this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to wrap each page inside your `PageView` in a `GestureDetector`, like this.

```
  PageView(
        children: [
          //Page1

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("Click page1");

              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => NewPage()
              ));

            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("text 1"),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          //Page2
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("Click page2");
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("text 1"),
                ),
              )),

          //Page3
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("Click page3");
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("text 1"),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      );
```